# how to append a row to a table with jquery in second position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, tablerow, prepend

I'm trying to add a row to a table with jquery. I would like to add the row in first position, but not the very first, I want it to come after the row dedicated to the column headers 'th'. If I try

```
$('#tableid').prepend()
```

obviously the new row comes before the one of 'th's. Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: can you show your table structure.?

Comment: Another case of USE thead and tbody! mark up tables like they were intended to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your first `tr` that holds the `th` you could do:

```
$('#tableid tr:first').after(newTrContent);
```

Or you if have them separated out into thead and tbody then you could just do.

```
$('#tableid tbody').prepend(newTrContent);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WHQY5/)**

Comment: yes, they both should work but the one of using thead and tbody tags in the structure of table I think is the right one. The first time I can understand what them tags are for :)

Comment: @Gabz Yes that would be a proper structure.